# Linq syntax to set values of Dictionary<long, List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, viewmodel

What is the Linq syntax to set a list of strings from a dictionary where the long Object.objectid matches the dictionary long?

For each person "member" in Members, if the long id matches, I want to add the string value from the List.

```
partial class BandMember
{
    public List<string> summary { get; set; }
}

public class BandViewModel
{
    public IList<BandMember> Members { get; set; }
}

public class BandMemberSummary : BandViewModel
{
    Dictionary<long, List<string>> _summary;

    public Dictionary<long, List<string>> Summary
    {

        get { return _summary; }
        set
        {
            _summary = value;

            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                List<string> list;
                if (_summary.TryGetValue(member.objectId, out list))
                    member.summary.AddRange(list);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

member.summary is a list of string values that is displayed in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `member.summary` is a `List<string>`, you can use the `List<T>.AddRange()` method to conveniently add all entries of an `IEnumerable<T>` to the List (a `List<string>` also implements `IEnumerable<string>`).

And when I interpret the member selection query correctly, this is nothing but acessing the entry with key `member.objectId` inside the dictionary, which can be simply done with the `[]` operator.

On your specific example, it would read as follows:

```
Dictionary<long, List<string>> _summary;

public Dictionary<long, List<string>> Summary
{
    get { return _summary; }
    set
    {
        _summary = value;

        foreach (var member in Members)
        {
            member.summary.AddRange(_summary[member.objectId]);
        }
    }
}
```

But, of course, this is only one possibility. You could als just run the loop yourself, and add each item manually. In fact, `AddRange` does probably not much more than that, but it looks more clean, if you are used to Linq.

In addition, if you are not sure, `_summary` already contains an entry for `member.objectId`, you could use the `TryGetValue` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This part would then read as:

```
Dictionary<long, List<string>> _summary;

public Dictionary<long, List<string>> Summary
{
    get { return _summary; }
    set
    {
        _summary = value;

        foreach (var member in Members)
        {
            List<string> list;
            if (_summary.TryGetValue(member.objectId, out list))
            {
                if (member.summary == null)
                    member.summary = new List<string>();
                member.summary.AddRange(list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should read `AddRange(l)`, not `1`. I changed the variable name to `list` in order to not confuse with the number 1.

Comment: Are you sure, that `member.summary` is initialized? Your error suggests, that it is still `null` and not an instance of a `List`.

Comment: @User970008 I already included the initialization in the last code edit. Did you try that version? And concerning your question: you typically initialize a class in the constructor. Partial class only means, that you split the class into multiple files. Somewhere has to be your constructor where you do the initialization.

Comment: What is null? out list cannot be null. list is null, but that does not matter. So, is _summary null, or member?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. Got it working. I do like the TryGetValue part of the solution especially.

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked out. Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is slightly better than your current query:

```
public Dictionary<long, List<string>> Summary
{
    get { return _summary; }
    set
    {
        _summary = value;

        foreach (var x in
            from member in Members
            join s in _summary on member.objectId equals s.Key
            select new { member, values = s.Value })
        {
            x.member.summary.AddRange(x.values);
        }
    }
}
```